# How to place the square inside of the grid box not at the crossing of it?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, heatmap

```
ggplot(HLA, aes(x = ID, y = Description, fill = BETA)) +
  geom_tile(width = 1, height = 1) + # Set the width and height of the squares to 1
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", 
                       midpoint = 0, # Set the midpoint of the color scale as 0
                       limits = c(-4, 2), # Set the limits of the color scale as -4 and 2
                       guide = "colorbar", # Use a color bar as the legend
                       breaks = c(-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2,3, 4)) + # Set the breaks for the legend
  labs(title = "Assocation Result", x = "HLA variant", y = "Phenotype", fill = "BETA") +
  theme_minimal() +# Use a minimal theme for the plot 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1)) + # Rotate the x labels 45 degrees
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "white", size = 0.5), # Set the color and size of the major grid lines
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), # Remove the minor grid lines
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey95", colour = NA)) # Set the background color of the plot
```

The square lie outside the grid, i want them to inside the box. How can i adjust the R code? The x and y are both categorical variables.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOhCD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxvEH.png)

Comment: Without your data is it not possible to replicate your plot so we can't help exactly, but see the documentation for `grid.panel.major` and `grid.panel.minor` for aesthetics, or `scale_y_continuous(breaks = ...)` and the like for setting where the lines lay.

Comment: If you just want the outline of the possible locations, maybe leave the grid blank as per `theme_minimal()` and just add `colour = "black"` to your `geom_tile()` arguments?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Thank you so much !!! It worked ! Really appreciate your help~

Answer (score 0):

The gridlines help align the tiles with the labels - presumably what you want therefore is a grid that outlines each possible tile?

attempt with built-in dataset:

```
data("HairEyeColor")

ggplot(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), aes(x = Hair, y = Eye, fill = Freq)) +
  geom_tile(width = 1, height = 1, colour = "grey6") +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", 
                       midpoint = 30,
                       limits = c(0, 70),
                       guide = "colorbar") +
  theme_minimal()
```

gives:
[image]